# Square Insufficient permissions to set app_fee_money when creating a payment

Tags: square-connect, square

1. I used Square Oauth to obtain `merchant_access_token` using the scopes

```
CUSTOMERS_WRITE
CUSTOMERS_READ
ITEMS_WRITE
ITEMS_READ
MERCHANT_PROFILE_WRITE
MERCHANT_PROFILE_READ
ORDERS_WRITE+ORDERS_READ
PAYMENTS_WRITE
PAYMENTS_READ
PAYMENTS_WRITE_ADDITIONAL_RECIPIENTS
```

from https://developer.squareup.com/docs/payments-api/take-payments-and-collect-fees

When I run the command, I get `Insufficient permissions to set app_fee_money`

I tried this from both the Application as well as Postman

What am I doing wrong?

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://connect.squareupsandbox.com/v2/payments' \
--header 'Square-Version: 2021-01-21' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer merchant_access_token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "source_id": "ccof:customer-card-id-ok",
    "idempotency_key": "6726cbd2-7893-4cc3-908e-c54731e9f1fe77979",
    "amount_money": {
        "amount": 5000,
        "currency": "USD"
    },
    "app_fee_money": {
        "amount": 1220,
        "currency": "USD"
    },
    "customer_id": "676YFJE8CCRPZ2K7F9C155JYP8",
    "location_id": "LG5CC4T0JXCX9", //Merchant location id
    "order_id": "M4C0LcxaW6DNpbyxE7sLypvbFA8zb4F",
    "reference_id": "M4C0LcxaW6DNpbyxE7sLypvbFA8zb4F",
    "statement_description_identifier": "Organization name",
    "note": "Fee note"
}'
```

Comment: I looked up that merchant account in sandbox and see that it's missing `PAYMENTS_WRITE_ADDITIONAL_RECIPIENTS` (it has all the others that you listed), so something didn't quite go right when authorizing. Can you try to recreate it, or share the OAuth auth link here?

Answer (score 1):

`PAYMENTS_WRITE_ADDITIONAL_RECIPIENTS` was in the code but older version of scopes without it was running, that fixed it. Thanks @sjosey